# Use oldstylenums with kpfonts in report class on everything BUT chapter/section heading counters

Tags: counters, oldstylenums, kpfonts

Kepler fonts (`kpfonts`) includes an `oldstylenums` options, which turns all numbers, including counters, in oldstyle numbers. Is there a way to use modern lining numbers for chapter and section counters in headings using the `report` class while preserving the oldstyle numbers for the rest of the document?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1234567890}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some random text 1234567890...
    \section{Section 1234567890}
    Here is some random text 1234567890...Here is some random text 1234567890...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would assume yes, but you didn't provide an example document for a test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, I'm new here. I've updated the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[oldstylenums]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\useclassicstylenums}{%
  \fontfamily{jkp\kp@stylemath\kp@famillem}\selectfont
}
\MakeRobust{\classicstylenums}

\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\useclassicstylenums}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\useclassicstylenums}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@sect}{\interlinepenalty\@M}{\interlinepenalty\@M\useclassicstylenums}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@ssect}{\interlinepenalty\@M}{\interlinepenalty\@M\useclassicstylenums}{}{}
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\classicstylenums{\csname the#1\endcsname}\quad}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{#1}{\classicstylenums{#1}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@dottedtocline}{#4}{\useclassicstylenums#4}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents 1234567890}% just to test \chapter*

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1234567890}

Here is some random text 1234567890...

\section{Section 1234567890}

Here is some random text 1234567890...

\section*{Section 1234567890}

Here is some random text 1234567890...

\subsection{Section 1234567890}

Here is some random text 1234567890...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the redefinition of `\contentsname` is done just to test an instance of `\chapter*` and is obviously not necessary for your document.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm; I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add after loading the `kpfonts`

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\classicstylenums{\arabic{chapter}}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\classicstylenums{\arabic{section}}}
```

Comment: it is normally not a good idea to add such formatting to the `\thecounter` commands. That will also affect references.

Comment: Sure…  but what else? ;-)